# XML Webservice for iSeries

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, ibm-midrange

I need to pull item quantity from a DB2 database from an aspx page and then update after the quantity has been changed.  I want to create a web service that will send XML data and then parse back to my page.  Looking for any good references or examples that anyone has possibly tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is another reason, I would suggest using C# to generate the web service for you. XML in C# is much better than the process to do it in RPG.